# How to overload by different dynamic-type in java8?

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming, java-8

How could I override a method by a dynamic-typed parameter? Or, is their any getting around for similar functionality?
Like this:

```
class a{
    public ArrayList<Movie> getEntries(Function<Movie, Boolean> filter){

    }
    public ArrayList<Ticket> getEntries(Function<Ticket, Boolean> filter){

    }
}
```

I have solved this problem by declaring getEntries as:

```
public <T extends Model> ArrayList<T> getEntries(Predicate<T> filter) { }
```

And, let Movie and Ticket extends Model.

Comment: You cant overload methods when different only generic types

Comment: You can't. There is no overloading for generics.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible because the Java compiler removes the generic information ([type erasure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure)) and this would lead to the class having two methods with the exact same method signature.

See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to use a `Predicate` rather than a `Function` for these.

You could write the following:

```
@FunctionalInterface interface MoviePredicate extends Predicate<Movie> {
}

@FunctionalInterface interface TicketPredicate extends Predicate<Ticket> {
}
```

Then your code can become:

```
class A {
  public List<Movie> getEntries(MoviePredicate filter){
  }
  public List<Ticket> getEntries(TicketPredicate filter){
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other wrote, due to type erasure you can't. Give the methods a different name.

```
class  A {
   private List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
   private List<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<>();

   public List<Movie> getMovies(Predicate<Movie> filter) {
        return movies.stream().filter(filter).collect(Collectors.toList());
   }

   public List<Ticket> getTickets(Predicate<Ticket> filter) {
        return tickets.stream().filter(filter).collect(Collectors.toList());
   }
}
```